# Filtering with Multiple Coloumn Variable List

Tags: batch-file

We are using a very simple query command to get a list of variable, and the format is quite similar (i.e- `004852 (space) E (space) STK@6.0, 004879 (space) BLANK (space) STK@6.0, 004883 (space) E (space) STK@6.0, 004892 (space) BLANK (space) STK@6.0`) like that, and we are using simple this line `| c:\windows\system32\find "E"` to sort the variables which are marked by “E”, but how could we sort the list which are marked by “Blank Space”?

Comment: `echo # #| find " "` works without problems.What's the problem to use just `find " "` ?

Comment: Already tried the same `| c:\windows\system32\find " "`, but it didn't work. I mean it's coming with all, as all the variable contained by (space) in the middle of two different column. Just forgot to mention.

Comment: Just a workaround `| c:\windows\system32\find /V "E"`, and beyond that `| c:\windows\system32\find /V "E" | c:\windows\system32\find /V "X/Y/Z"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working so far, for the above mentioned problem.
`| c:\windows\system32\find /V "E"`